# Contagem incorreta em programa de urna eletrônica

Tags: c

Criei uma urna com a linguagem C.
O código aparentemente está correto, porém a contagem de votos sempre resulta em zero. O código foi desenvolvido no code:blocks em Linux, portanto para que funcione em windows, as linhas dos comandos sleep e system("clear") devem ser mudadas ou comentadas.

Os votos possíveis são 1, 2, 3 e 4 para os candidatos, 111 para voto branco ou nulo e 999 para apuração/fechamento da urna.

segue abaixo o código:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


int votar()
{

    int candidato, confirmador, nulo, c1, c2, c3, c4;

    nulo = 0;
    c1 = 0;
    c2 = 0;
    c3 = 0;
    c4 = 0;

    system("clear");
    printf("Para Voto NULO ou BRANCO, digite 111 no candidato.\n\nDigite o numero do candidato:");
    scanf("%d",&candidato);

    switch(candidato)
    {

        case 111:

            system("clear");
            printf("Seu voto é: NULO OU BRANCO \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&confirmador);

            if(confirmador==1)
            {
               // nulo++;
               nulo = nulo +1;
                system("clear");
                printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
                sleep (5);

            }
            if(confirmador==2)
            {
                votar();
            }
            if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
            }

            votar();

            break;


        case 999:

            //apuracao(c1, c2, c3, c4);
    printf("*****************************************\n");
    printf("ELEICOES 2016 - PESQUISA - PREFEITOS\n");
    printf("*****************************************\n");

    printf("\nJOAO: %d VOTOS\n",c1);
    printf("\nJOAQUIM %d VOTOS\n",c2);
    printf("\nJOANA: %d VOTOS\n",c3);
    printf("\nJULIA: %d VOTOS\n",c4);
    printf("\nBRANCOS OU NULOS: %d VOTOS\n",nulo);

    sleep (60);

        break;

        case 1:

            system("clear");
            printf("Seu candidato é: JOAO \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&confirmador);

            if(confirmador==1)
            {
               // c1++;
               c1 = c1 +1;
                system("clear");
                printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
                sleep (5);

            }
            if(confirmador==2)
            {
                votar();
            }
            if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
            }

            votar();

            break;

        case 2:

            system("clear");
            printf("Seu candidato é: JOAQUIM \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&confirmador);

            if(confirmador==1)
            {
               // c2++;
               c2 = c2 +1;
                system("clear");
                printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
                sleep (5);

            }
            if(confirmador==2)
            {
                votar();
            }
            if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
            }

        case 3:

            system("clear");
            printf("Seu candidato é: JOANA \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&confirmador);

            if(confirmador==1)
            {
               // c3++;
               c3 = c3 +1;
                system("clear");
                printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
                sleep (5);

            }
            if(confirmador==2)
            {
                votar();
            }
            if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
            }

        case 4:

            system("clear");
            printf("Seu candidato é: JULIA \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
            scanf("%d",&confirmador);

            if(confirmador==1)
            {
               // c4++;
               c4 = c4 +1;
                system("clear");
                printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
                sleep (5);

            }
            if(confirmador==2)
            {
                votar();
            }
            if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
            {
                system("clear");
                printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
            }

        default:

            system("clear");
            printf("Candidato invalido, digite o numero do partido. \n\n");
            sleep(5);

            }

    votar();

}

int apuracao(int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int nulo)
{

    printf("*****************************************\n");
    printf("ELEICOES 2016 - PESQUISA - PREFEITOS\n");
    printf("*****************************************\n");

    printf("\nJOAO: %d VOTOS\n",c1);
    printf("\nJOAQUIM %d VOTOS\n",c2);
    printf("\nJOANA: %d VOTOS\n",c3);
    printf("\nJULIA: %d VOTOS\n",c4);
    printf("\nBRANCOS OU NULOS: %d VOTOS\n",nulo);


    return 0;
}

int main()
{

    printf("*****************************************\n");
    printf("ELEICOES 2016 - PESQUISA - PREFEITOS\n");
    printf("*****************************************\n");

    printf("\n\nBem-vindo(a) a pesquisa eleitoral 2016.\nEste programa e experimental e de codigo livre.\nPara encerrar a sessao, basta digitar 999 no campo candidato.\nPara iniciar aperte qualquer tecla.\n\n");
    getchar();

    votar();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Só pra confirmar: você está trabalhando com C e não C++, correto? Você colocou as duas tags e são linguagens bem diferentes.

Comment: Sim, estou trabalhando em C, errei na hora de colocar as Tags.

Comment: O lado bom é que, mesmo da forma que está, já é mais confiável que nossas urnas eletrônicas aqui no Brasil. Pelo menos seu código a gente tem como conferir publicamente.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nulo, c1, c2, c3, c4, agora são globais, estava faltando dois votar() e break, foi necessário mudar a declaração de variáveis da função votar, e em vez de usar função recursiva você deveria incluir seu programa num loop infinito talvez com condição de saída.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<unistd.h>


int nulo;
int c1;
int c2;
int c3;
int c4;

int votar() {

int candidato, confirmador;


system("clear");
printf("Para Voto NULO ou BRANCO, digite 111 no candidato.\n\nDigite o numero do candidato:");
scanf("%d",&candidato);

switch(candidato)
{

    case 111:

        system("clear");
        printf("Seu voto é: NULO OU BRANCO \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&confirmador);

        if(confirmador==1)
        {
           // nulo++;
           nulo = nulo +1;
            system("clear");
            printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar! \n\n\n");
            sleep (5);

        }
        if(confirmador==2)
        {
            votar();
        }
        if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
        }

        votar();

        break;


    case 999:

        //apuracao(c1, c2, c3, c4);
printf("*****************************************\n");
printf("ELEICOES 2016 - PESQUISA - PREFEITOS\n");
printf("*****************************************\n");

printf("\nJOAO: %d VOTOS\n",c1);
printf("\nJOAQUIM %d VOTOS\n",c2);
printf("\nJOANA: %d VOTOS\n",c3);
printf("\nJULIA: %d VOTOS\n",c4);
printf("\nBRANCOS OU NULOS: %d VOTOS\n",nulo);

sleep (60);

    break;

    case 1:

        system("clear");
        printf("Seu candidato é: JOAO \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&confirmador);

        if(confirmador==1)
        {
           // c1++;
           c1 = c1 +1;
            system("clear");
            printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
            sleep (5);

        }
        if(confirmador==2)
        {
            votar();
        }
        if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
        }

        votar();

        break;

    case 2:

        system("clear");
        printf("Seu candidato é: JOAQUIM \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&confirmador);

        if(confirmador==1)
        {
           // c2++;
           c2 = c2 +1;
            system("clear");
            printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
            sleep (5);

        }
        if(confirmador==2)
        {
            votar();
        }
        if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
        }
        votar();
        break;

    case 3:

        system("clear");
        printf("Seu candidato é: JOANA \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&confirmador);

        if(confirmador==1)
        {
           // c3++;
           c3 = c3 +1;
            system("clear");
            printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
            sleep (5);

        }
        if(confirmador==2)
        {
            votar();
        }
        if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
        }
        votar();
        break;

    case 4:

        system("clear");
        printf("Seu candidato é: JULIA \nConfirma o voto? \n\n1-CONFIRMA\n2-CANCELAR\n\n");
        scanf("%d",&confirmador);

        if(confirmador==1)
        {
           // c4++;
           c4 = c4 +1;
            system("clear");
            printf("Voto confirmado, obrigado por votar!\n\n\n");
            sleep (5);

        }
        if(confirmador==2)
        {
            votar();
        }
        if((confirmador!=1)&&(confirmador!=2))
        {
            system("clear");
            printf("Opcao invalida, digite 1 para CONFIRMAR ou 2 para CANCELAR.");
        }

    default:

        system("clear");
        printf("Candidato invalido, digite o numero do partido. \n\n");
        sleep(5);

        }

votar();

}

int apuracao(int c1, int c2, int c3, int c4, int nulo) {

printf("*****************************************\n");
printf("ELEICOES 2016 - PESQUISA - PREFEITOS\n");
printf("*****************************************\n");

printf("\nJOAO: %d VOTOS\n",c1);
printf("\nJOAQUIM %d VOTOS\n",c2);
printf("\nJOANA: %d VOTOS\n",c3);
printf("\nJULIA: %d VOTOS\n",c4);
printf("\nBRANCOS OU NULOS: %d VOTOS\n",nulo);


return 0;

}

int main() {


nulo = 0;
c1 = 0;
c2 = 0;
c3 = 0;
c4 = 0;
printf("*****************************************\n");
printf("ELEICOES 2016 - PESQUISA - PREFEITOS\n");
printf("*****************************************\n");

printf("\n\nBem-vindo(a) a pesquisa eleitoral 2016.\nEste programa e experimental e de codigo livre.\nPara encerrar a sessao, basta digitar 999 no campo candidato.\nPara iniciar aperte qualquer tecla.\n\n");
getchar();

votar();

return 0;

}
```

Comment: Muito Obragado pela sua resposta e as demais que ajudaram na conclusão do programa, agora está do modo que idealizei!

Answer (score 1):

Você zera as variáveis toda vez que a função votar é chamada.

Declare as variáveis de contagem fora da função, assim se tornarão globais, e não terão seu valor reiniciado.

Outra opção é colocar sua lógica de votação dentro de um laço :

```
while(candidato != 999){
  // faça a leitura e atribua um novo valor à variável candidato.

}
```

Quando sair do laço você exibe a contagem.

Answer (score 1):

Sua função "votar" é recursiva, isto é, ela se chama de novo internamente!

Função recursivas têm sua utilidade, mas são usadas relativamente pouco.

No seu caso, a cada chamada recursiva as variáveis de contagem são todas zeradas!

Tente re-escrever o exercício sem utilizar uma função recursiva, que é desnecessária neste caso.